# Format of ssh config

Tags: git, github, ssh

I followed a tutorial so I could have two seperate git hub users on the same machine, I created a config in the ssh folder:

```
#Default GitHub
Host <span class="skimlinks-unlinked">github.com</span>
HostName <span class="skimlinks-unlinked">github.com</span>
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Host github-panthro
HostName <span class="skimlinks-unlinked">github.com</span>
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_panthro
```

But now when I try and ssh I get the error:

```
config line 3: garbage at end of line; "class".
```

I've cleaned up the class removing whitespace but still the error persists.

Comment: please post link to the tutorial you followed

Comment: i am really sure the `<span class=...>` shouldn't be there. did you copy paste that by mistake to/from your ssh config file?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Delete the Span as follows and it should work. I have the similar config file that works.

```
Host github.com
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
Host github-panthro
HostName github.com
User git
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_panthro
```